# Add legend to jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using a standard jQuery Datepicker and I need to modify it to display legend on the bottom. When I use beforeShow event, I cant append legend html to datepicker because there is no #ui-datepicker-div element, and datepicker does not supply afterShow event. This is my code:

```
var html = $('#datepickerLegendHolder').html();

$('#start_date.datepicker').datepicker({
        "dateFormat": 'yy-mm-dd', 
        minDate: 0, 
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "/images/calendar-icon.png",
        maxDate: "+2Y",
        beforeShow: function(event, ui) { 
            $('#ui-datepicker-div').append(html);
        },
        onSelect: function (dateValue, inst) {
            $('#end_date.datepicker').datepicker("option", "minDate", dateValue);
            displayButtons();
        }
    });
```

Have anyone some alternative? Tnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time the `onBeforeShow` event is raised, the element `#ui-datepicker-div` does not exists yet.

A workaround is to use a [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) with a small duration (like 150ms) to append your legend to that element in the event handler. It could not be totally reliable although because of the architecture of the plugin, I don't know any other way.

*Note: the documentation lists to a [create](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-create) event but the Datepicker does implement the Widget Factory so there is actually no create event raised !*

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    ...
    beforeShow: function(event, ui) { 
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#ui-datepicker-div').append('lalala');
        }, 150);
    }
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/c64g2/)**

Comment: Actually, I have tried with timeout() function, but was using create event, and smaller timeout time, and didn't worked. Anyway, it does not diminish your help :) Tnx!

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation of jQuery UI is pretty bad IMO. The "create" event only exists for widgets using the Widget Factory and the datepicker does not implement it (yet). Anyway, glad it helped !